# php for calling rank as a new column giving out the same value

Tags: php

i still need help of how to call this rank data in php as a new column.

so, i have this table

[image]

and here is the code

```html
 <?php 
   $rank="SELECT student_code, led2dt4engavgfinal,      
                FIND_IN_SET(led2dt4engavgfinal  (
                SELECT  GROUP_CONCAT(
                DISTINCT led2dt4engavgfinal
                ORDER BY led2dt4engavgfinal  ASC)
                FROM    led2deng)) as rank FROM   led2deng";
  $myQry2 = mysql_query($rank, $koneksidb)  or die ("Query salah : ".mysql_error());
  $myData2 = mysql_fetch_array($myQry2);
?>
```

when i call the data with this code

```html
<td <strong><?php echo  $myData2['rank']; ?></strong></div></td>
```

it came out all rows have the same values.

[image]

what i want is to have the rank as displayed on the table of first image above.
anyone can help?

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish with FIND_IN_SET?

Comment: could you please share with us the tables one by one? Your php code looks like normal, and the problem in your SQL query..

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a simple query like this?

```
SELECT student_code, led2dt4engavgfinal, rank FROM led2deng;
```

Answer (score -1):

Change

```
<td <strong><?php echo  $myData2['rank']; ?></strong></div></td>
```

to

```
while ($myData2 = mysql_fetch_array($myQry2))
{
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td><strong>" . $myData2['led2dt4engavgfinal'] . "</strong></td>";
    echo "<td><strong>" . $myData2['rank'] . "</strong></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

You'll also want your other columns to be inside the while loop.

Comment: it came out all rank in one row...not in column, like the image above

Comment: Answer updated to include `<tr>` tags and an example of how to display other columns.